# Open pptx in network path

Tags: python

I am trying to open an pptx in network path but it always gives me "No such file or directory:", and when I run it in cmd there is result.

So far I already tried this code:

```
path = r"\\10.10.10.211\My Docs\Me\Test.pptx"
subprocess.Popen(path)
```

and

```
path = r"\\10.10.10.211\My Docs\Me\Test.pptx"
open(path)
```

Any advice or suggestion, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the full command you run on the command line?

Comment: Im just accessing this >>> \\10.10.10.211\My Docs\Me\Test.pptx